# Remove duplicated word from a file

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a text file of format something like

```
path1/path2/path3a 34474538656
path1/path2/path3a 8115147679
path1/path2/path3b 2266371027
path1/path2/path3b 3860823 
path1/path2/path3b 554247
```

And this pattern continues. I am looking to remove only the column 1 duplicate entry and print it as

```
path1/path2/path3a 34474538656
                   8115147679
path1/path2/path3b 2266371027
                   3860823 
                   554247
```

Is this possible?

The columns are delimited by a single space

All paths have same length

Globally aligned would be preferred to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
$ awk '{ print seen[$1]++ ? "                   "$2 : $0}' file
path1/path2/path3a 34474538656
                   8115147679
path1/path2/path3b 2266371027
                   3860823
                   554247
```

Which could also be written as:

```
$ awk -v spacer='                   ' '{ print seen[$1]++ ? spacer$2 : $0}' file
path1/path2/path3a 34474538656
                   8115147679
path1/path2/path3b 2266371027
                   3860823
                   554247
```

Or

```
$ awk -v spacer='                   ' '{ if(seen[$1]++){print spacer$2}else{print}}' file
path1/path2/path3a 34474538656
                   8115147679
path1/path2/path3b 2266371027
                   3860823
                   554247
```

Or, in `perl`, calculating the length of the spacer on the fly:

```
$ perl -lane '$spacer=$seen{$F[0]}++ ? " " x length($F[0]) : $F[0]; print "$spacer $F[1]"' file
path1/path2/path3a 34474538656
                   8115147679
path1/path2/path3b 2266371027
                   3860823
                   554247
```

Answer (score 5):

Another implementation

```bash
awk '
    $1 == prev {gsub(/./, " ", $1); changed = 1}
    !changed {prev = $1}
    {print; changed = 0}
' file
```

Comment: Longer than mine, but more versatile since you're calculating the size and more elegant. Nice!

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, but here's my solution:

```
awk '{this = $1 ; if (this == last) {gsub(/./, " ", $1)} ; last = this ; print $0}' input
```

#### Features

- Indent for a duplicate path is automatically the same length as the path
- Doesn't store every path seen (which could be problematic at very high volumes)
- Allows for unsorted input (side effect of ^^)